# php form sending everything but the message

Tags: php, forms, email

I inherited this form and i am not a coder so not sure why they form is not sending the message...just email and the name from the form.

Here is code

```
    <?php
    echo 111;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //Sending Email to form owner
    $header = "From: $email\n"
    . "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $subject = "Skills Generation Contact Form";
    $email_to = "mail@skillsgen.com";
    $message = "name: $name"
    . "email: $email\n"
    . "message: $message";
    if (mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ))
    {
    // Message was successfully sent
        // To redirect form on a particular page
    header("Location:http://www.skillsgeneration.com.au");

    }
    echo 123;
    ?>
```

Comment: where is the html form? did you call everything the right name? do you have a live link?

Comment: not sure http://www.skillsgeneration.com.au/

Comment: you didn't include the $_POST['message'] in your $message., try this $message = "name: $name". "email: $email."$message"\n";

Comment: <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Sending Email to form owner
$header = "From: $email\n"
. "Reply-To: $email\n";
$subject = "Skills Generation Contact Form";
$email_to = "mail@skillsgenerations.com";
$message = "name: $name". "email: $email."$message"\n";
. "email: $email\n";
mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ) ;
{
// To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:http://www.skillsgeneration.com.au");
}
?>

Comment: Is that right...it made the results page go all blank and didn't email it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html you did not give the textarea a name

change:

```
<textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message ';}">Your Message</textarea>
```

to:

```
<textarea name="message" value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message ';}">Your Message</textarea>
```

like @Bankzilla said you are also overwriting the $message variable.

replace it with something like:

```
$message = "name: $name"."email: $email\n message:$message";
```

Comment: ok I have changed the html and the results page but the page is going to blank on submit and not emailing form through?? Any ideas

Comment: did you remove the parentheses like @Bankzilla suggested? are php erros on?

Comment: Yes just uploaded changes and getting white screen on submit?

Comment: Should it be 

."email: $email\n".$message;

or
. "email: $email\n";
. "message: $message";

Comment: try adding 'echo 123;' at the end of the script and see if you get a blank screen with 123 text

Comment: did you add the echo to the end of the file ( 1 line before the '?>' )? try adding 'echo 111;' to the start of the file as well

Comment: send me the file. include it in your question

Comment: I have updated the code above in my question ...is that what you meant

Comment: remove ';' from the line . "email: $email\n";

Comment: I Love you I love you I love you! Thank you sooooo much for your patience and persistence. I really appreciate it!

Comment: if you like my answer please like it :)

Comment: done thanks again so I guess I just remove the echo stuff now

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code it's because you're overwriting the `$message` variable with `$message = "name: $name". "email: $email\n";`.

I'm not to sure what you're trying to achieve with the open parentheses around the header method.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Sending Email to form owner
$header = "From: $email\n"
. "Reply-To: $email\n";
$subject = "Website Form";
$email_to = "mail@email.com";
$message = "name: $name"
. "email: $email\n";
. "message: $message";
if(mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ))
{
    // Message was successfully sent
    // To redirect form on a particular page
    header("Location:http://www.website.com.au");
}
?>
```

Comment: I inherited this site and just trying to fix with my very basic php knowledge so no idea either